# Changed version of Spark to 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT and get parquet error only in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I built Spark 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT locally and did

```
mvn install -Phadoop-2.6 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 <other spark opts>
```

on it.    Running a *custom spark program* that uses that *spark-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT* dependency (reading from local maven repo) is working: parquet output files are being produced as expected.

However in the same project (which *does* build ..) but running the *main* from Intellij is giving the following exception:

```
in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext;Lorg/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$buildInternalScan$1$$anon$1.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$buildInternalScan$1.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$buildInternalScan$1.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withDummyCallSite(Utils.scala:2132)
```

Within Intellij I have done `Project|Rebuild` many times to no avail. That is in addition to having done mvn clean on the command line multiple times.

In intellij I checked the dependencies list (all maven). It is correct in the sense that only Spark-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT shows up (not the earlier version of spark).

The command I am running is actually only going to local file system not even through hdfs. Also I am running against `local[*]` for spark master.  So there are no external dependencies - either Spark or Hadoop -outside of the project itself.

What may be done to fix this error only occurring within Intellij?